# Максимум 2 чисел

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как правильно написать шаблонную функцию для нахождения максимума двух чисел?

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: @AlexanderChernin мне своя нужна, а не стандартная

Comment: Там есть примеры написания "правильно"

Comment: @AlexanderChernin что интересно, как раз таки нет

Comment: так вы тогда уточняйте насколько шаблонная функция вам нужна, вариант александра ок, для одинаковых типов данных вполне рабочая вещь, а если вам надо сравнивать лонг / флоат или может строки, то это ВАЖНАЯ часть вопроса

Comment: @goldstar_labs вариант Александра не ок в любом случае, важно мне это или нет

Comment: @Bog Я уже не в том возрасте, чтобы все знать ) то, есть не теоретик - если мне нужен максимум из двух значений, то я вызываю std::max, если что-то идет не так, то иду дальше. Заниматься теоретическим рафинадом просто некогда, да и не хочется )

Comment: Что такое "правильно"? Стандартная функция возвращает lvalue - это входит в требование "правильности" или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы делал [примерно так](https://ideone.com/bMNLhW)

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::common_type<T, U>::type max(const T& a, const U& b)
{
    if (a > b) return a;
    return b;
}
```

Не буду утверждать, что это наилучший идеальный вариант :)

P.S. Появилась минутка, чтоб не долго мучиться, построил вариативный вариант на основе уже имеющегося:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename common_type<T,U>::type max(const T& a, const U& b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
auto max(const T& a, const U& b, Args... arg)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(arg) == 0)
        return max(a,b);
    return max(max(a,b),arg...);
}
```

Comment: Красиво. Это с++14?

Comment: Пока что это лучший вариант

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Честно говоря, уже и не скажу, какого именно года :) - они уже так перепутались, что просто - более-менее современного :) Как там в ключиках у VC++ - `/std:latest` :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так [std max](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max):

```
template<class T>
const T& max(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return (a < b) ? b : a;
}
```

В моей системе, в заголовнике algorithm сделано так.

```
namespace std {
...
template<typename _Tp, typename _Compare>
_GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
inline const _Tp&
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
{
    //return __comp(__a, __b) ? __b : __a;
    if (__comp(__a, __b))
        return __b;
    return __a;
}
```

Comment: И чему равен `max(2, 3.5)`? Если уж делать, то не стандартную, а более мощную версию :)

Comment: При таком вызове вы получите template argument deduction/substitution failed, после чего на практике вы подправите и напишете max<double>(2, 3.5) и получите 3.5 ;)

Comment: @Harry причём эта версия не стандартная даже :)

Comment: @Bog она в std ))

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вы же сами привели ссылку https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max, а вообще http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.min.max

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
template<typename TA, typename TB, typename TR = std::common_type_t<TA, TB>>
TR max(TA a, TB b) {
  return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```